# udf in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have two dataframes: dataDf and regexDf.  dataDf has large number of records and regexDf has two columns of regex.  My problem is, i need to filter dataDf based on two of its column matching regular expression in two columns in regexDef.  I came up with this

```
dataDf.registerTempTable("dataTable")
sqlContext.udf.register("matchExpressionCombination", matchExpressionCombination _)

val matchingResults = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE matchExpressionCombination(col1, col2)")
def matchExpressionCombination(col1Text: String, col2Text: String): Boolean = {
  val regexDf = getRegexDf()
  var isMatch = false
  for(row <- regexDf.collect) {
    if(col1Text.matches(row(0).toString) && col2Text.matches(row(1).toString)) {
      isMatch = true
    }
  }
  isMatch
}
```

when i say

```
matchingResults.count().println
```

​I get the following error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[count#118L])
 TungstenExchange SinglePartition
  TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[currentCount#121L])
   Union
    TungstenProject
     Filter UDF(Col1Text#97,Col2Text#109)
      Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf1.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#97,BaselineStacktrace#98,BaselineTime#99,ClassId#100,ClassName#101,Id#102,IsDataSilo#103,MethodName#104,Namespace#105,Organization#106,PackageName#107,TestResultKey#108,Col2Text#109,UpgradedStacktrace#110,UpgradedTime#111]
    TungstenProject
     Filter UDF(Col1Text#2,Col2Text#14)
      Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf2.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#2,BaselineStacktrace#3,BaselineTime#4,ClassId#5,ClassName#6,Id#7,IsDataSilo#8,MethodName#9,Namespace#10,Organization#11,PackageName#12,TestResultKey#13,Col2Text#14,UpgradedStacktrace#15,UpgradedTime#16]


    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate.doExecute(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.count(DataFrame.scala:1403)
    at com.salesforce.hammer.clusterer.collector.DeduperTest$.applyBaselineAndUpgradeOnlyPatternTest(DeduperTest.scala:83)
    at com.salesforce.hammer.clusterer.collector.Application$.main(Main.scala:53)
    at com.salesforce.hammer.clusterer.collector.Application.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
TungstenExchange SinglePartition
 TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[currentCount#121L])
  Union
   TungstenProject
     Filter UDF(Col1Text#97,Col2Text#109)
      Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf1.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#97,BaselineStacktrace#98,BaselineTime#99,ClassId#100,ClassName#101,Id#102,IsDataSilo#103,MethodName#104,Namespace#105,Organization#106,PackageName#107,TestResultKey#108,Col2Text#109,UpgradedStacktrace#110,UpgradedTime#111]
    TungstenProject
     Filter UDF(Col1Text#2,Col2Text#14)
      Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf2.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#2,BaselineStacktrace#3,BaselineTime#4,ClassId#5,ClassName#6,Id#7,IsDataSilo#8,MethodName#9,Namespace#10,Organization#11,PackageName#12,TestResultKey#13,Col2Text#14,UpgradedStacktrace#15,UpgradedTime#16]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.doExecute(Exchange.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
TungstenAggregate(key=[], functions=[(count(1),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[currentCount#121L])
 Union

TungstenProject
     Filter UDF(Col1Text#97,Col2Text#109)
      Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf1.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#97,BaselineStacktrace#98,BaselineTime#99,ClassId#100,ClassName#101,Id#102,IsDataSilo#103,MethodName#104,Namespace#105,Organization#106,PackageName#107,TestResultKey#108,Col2Text#109,UpgradedStacktrace#110,UpgradedTime#111]
    TungstenProject
     Filter UDF(Col1Text#2,Col22Text#14)
      Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf2.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#2,BaselineStacktrace#3,BaselineTime#4,ClassId#5,ClassName#6,Id#7,IsDataSilo#8,MethodName#9,Namespace#10,Organization#11,PackageName#12,TestResultKey#13,Col2Text#14,UpgradedStacktrace#15,UpgradedTime#16]


    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate.doExecute(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2021)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:703)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1.apply(RDD.scala:702)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.mapPartitions(RDD.scala:702)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TungstenProject.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Union$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Union$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:184)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Union.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.salesforce.RegexDeduper
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.salesforce.RegexDeduper, value: com.salesforce.RegexDeduper@67b464f4)
    - field (class: com.salesforce.RegexDeduper$$anonfun$applyCol1TextAndCol2TextPattern$1, name: $outer, type: class com.salesforce.RegexDeduper)
    - object (class com.salesforce.RegexDeduper$$anonfun$applyBaselineAndUpgradePattern$1, <function2>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$3, name: func$3, type: interface scala.Function2)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$3, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, name: f, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF, UDF(Col1Text#97,Col2Text#109))
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter, name: condition, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Expression)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter, Filter UDF(Col1Text#97,Col2Text#109)
 Scan CsvRelation(playWithSpark/data/dataDf1.csv,true,,,",null,#,PERMISSIVE,COMMONS,false,false,null,UTF-8,false)[Col1Text#97,BaselineStacktrace#98,BaselineTime#99,ClassId#100,ClassName#101,Id#102,IsDataSilo#103,MethodName#104,Namespace#105,Organization#106,PackageName#107,TestResultKey#108,Col2TText#109,UpgradedStacktrace#110,UpgradedTime#111]
)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter$$anonfun$4, name: $outer, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Filter$$anonfun$4, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use collect operation in UDF as all data will be shipped to that node, and collect should be used only for experiments in spark-shell kind of environment not in production 
In addition to this you can't use any operation which uses spark context as these operations are performed on the driver but UDF code is shipped to Executor nodes and Executor doesn't have spark context object

Answer (score 1):

Your UDF `matchExpressionCombination` will be called for every row in `dataTable`, but it involves collecting an RDD (`regexDf.collect`). This will lead to the collect operation being performed once per row of 'dataTable`, which should be very inefficient.

You should either join the RDDs, using a UDF function to determine where the tables match, or collect the regex RDD once outside of your UDF into a local val and use that val within your UDF.

Your exception shows `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.salesforce.RegexDeduper` so you should probably give more detail on where this class is being used within your code.

Comment: yes that did the trick.  RegexDeduper needed to implement Serializable and i had to move out few class members which i did not want to serialize